# Hexbin: how to trace bin contents

Tags: r, binning

After applying [hexbin](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hexbin)'ning I would like to know which id or rownumbers of the original data ended up in which bin.

I am currently analysing spatial data and I am binning, e.g., depth of water and temperature. Ideally, I would like to map the colormap of the bins back to the spatial map to see where more or less common parameter combinations exist. I'm not bound to `hexbin` though.
I wasn't able to figure out from the documentation, how to trace which datapoint ends up in which bin. It seems `hexbin()` only stores counts.

Is there a function that generates a list with one entry for every bin, each containing a vector of all rownumbers that were assigned to that bin?

Please point me into the right direction.

Up to now, I use plain hexbin to do the binning:

```
library(hexbin)
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(depth=runif(1000,min=0,max=100),temp=runif(1000,min=4,max=14))
h <- hexbin(df)
```

but currently I see no way to extract rownames of df from h that link the bins to df. Possibly there is no such thing, maybe I overlooked it or there is a completely different approach needed.

Comment: How are you currently doing binning? Please edit your question to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the code you are currently running. This will make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the `hexbin` package, then you will need to set `IDs=TRUE` to be able to go back to the original rows

```
library(hexbin)
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(depth=runif(1000,min=0,max=100),temp=runif(1000,min=4,max=14))
h<-hexbin(df, IDs=TRUE)
```

Then to get the bin number for each observation, you can use

```
h@cID
```

To get the count of observations in the cell populated by a particular observation, you would do

```
h@count[match(h@cID, h@cell)]
```

The idea is that the second observation `df[2,]` is in cell `h@cID[2]=424`. Cell 424 is at index `which(h@cell==424)=241` in the list of cells (zero count cells appear to be omitted). The number of observations in that cell is `h@count[241]=2`.